# GDDR Power Calculation

Tags: power, memory, ddr, ddr3, dram

I'm wondering if there is any publicly available documents or research papers that cover GDDR power estimation?

Micron provides very nice [documentation and calculators](https://www.micron.com/support/power-calc) for DDR up to DDR4, however I cannot find anything for GDDR.

I understand that GDDR is based on DDR, but how similar are they when it comes to calculating power?

[GPUWattch Publication](https://www.ece.ubc.ca/~aamodt/papers/gpuwattch.isca2013.pdf)

Comment: The underlying technology is the same for both devices -- it's capacitor-based DRAM. You haven't specified what type of GDDR you're interested in, so I'll talk about GDDR5. Electrically, it's most similar to DDR3, not DDR4. GDDR5 runs at much, much higher clock frequencies (generally) in addition to having some protocol differences (prefetch, etc.). I'd argue your primary power consumption drivers are going to be voltage and clock frequency -- using an existing power estimator for DDR3 but using GDDR like frequencies may be a decent start...

Comment: @KrunalDesai Thanks, I did have GDDR5 in mind. My concern about the differences are due to a paragraph in the GPUWattch paper (link in post), which says "We found no public information on GDDR3/5 power modeling and while flexible DRAM power models [35] could be incorporated into our effort, they require additional reverse engineering of the GDDR implementation".